# Odoo XPath Error in Studio Editing when adding and item

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

It gave me the following error message when try to add any item there "This operation caused an error, probably because a xpath was broken".

I've tried to add a new item such as text field and it has to be added usually, but it refused with error message.

Comment: please provide your xml code and the parent view-key and code